# My youtube videos stopped playing when I switched to SSL encryption of my site

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have a website that plays youtube videos in iframes.  It also controls them with javascript commands that make them pause, restart, etc.   This site works well, but recently I bought a SSL certificate to make it more secure.  Now the youtube videos will not play any more.  I thought that maybe the reason was that using a encrypted page requires an encrypted video, but even if that's true, the code I use to make the iframe doesn't allow for any specification of https.  The code is something like:

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '592',
                width: '789',
                videoId: 'Hd8MFmUDbg4',
                wmode: 'transparent',
                playerVars: { 'controls': 1, 'fs': 0, 'autoplay': 1, 'autohide': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0},
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
```

So the question is - **is there any way to play a youtube video in a site that uses SSL?**   (I  can't use regular iframe syntax, because there is a bug in combining iframes with asp.net pages and keeping the website secure.  It has to be done via the above "new" statement.)

Comment: What is exactly happening? There is a known issue where a mixed warning pops up here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2964&can=1&q=youtube%20https&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

but nothing mentioned that I won't work on SSL sites. Probaly you are running into problems when referring to the YT JS API file via HTTP.. try to refer to the https one.

Comment: You are correct.  I use jquery libraries for this page, and these libraries are from external sites (ajax.google.com).  They are not encrypted, and in Google Chrome including them in a website that has been converted to use SSL means that they are simply skipped, or ignored.  Once I tried the site in Internet Explorer, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running into problems when referring to the YT JS API file via HTTP.. try to refer to the https one.

Just make sure all libraries are loaded from HTTPS :)

( See my comment [My youtube videos stopped playing when I switched to SSL encryption of my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272657/my-youtube-videos-stopped-playing-when-i-switched-to-ssl-encryption-of-my-site##comment-21545533) )

And now mark this question as answered please ;)